# Error on a FromRow instance definition with postgres-simple

Tags: postgresql, haskell, aeson

```
data CumulativeRevenue = CumulativeRevenue
  { payment_date :: T.Text
  , amount       :: Double
  , sum          :: Double
  } deriving (Show, Generic, Aeson.ToJSON, Aeson.FromJSON)

instance Postgres.FromRow CumulativeRevenue where
  fromRow = CumulativeRevenue
            <$> Postgres.field
            <*> Postgres.field
            <*> Postgres.field

cumulativeRevenue :: Postgres.Connection -> IO [CumulativeRevenue]
cumulativeRevenue conn = Postgres.query_ conn
  "SELECT payment_date, amount, sum(amount) OVER (ORDER by payment_date) \
  \ FROM (\
  \ SELECT CAST (payment_date as TEXT) AS payment_date, SUM(amount) AS \
  \ amount \
  \ FROM payment \
  \ GROUP BY CAST(payment_date AS TEXT) \
  \ ) p \
  \ ORDER BY payment_date \
  \"
```

Currently, I have the above piece of code. Complete code is [here](https://gitlab.com/SanchayanMaity/postgres-play/blob/master/src/Lib.hs). The cumulativeRevenue is giving an exception as below. You can ignore the spock part.

```
Spock Error while handling ["cumulative"]: Incompatible {errSQLType = "numeric", errSQLTableOid = Nothing, errSQLField = "amount", errHaskellType = "Double", errMessage = "types incompatible"}
```

I am not clear on what to specify for the amount and sum fields in CumulativeRevenue. Can someone help me with that? Is there some easier way to figure out the type conversions from Haskell types to SQL types or vice versa while using postgres-simple library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `FromField` instance for `Double`, but it doesn't work with `numeric`, because `numeric` is variable-precision [as per the PostgresSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-numeric.html). If you look at the [`postgresql-simple` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.6.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple-FromField.html) you'll see that the `Ratio Integer` (aka `Rational`) instance *does* support `numeric`.

So what you can do here is one of two things:

1. Use `Rational` instead of `Double` for your `amount` field
2. Decide that you're alright with losing precision (although why are you using `numeric` on the SQL side then?), and do something like

```
import Data.Ratio

loseNumericPrecision :: Postgres.RowParser Double
loseNumericPrecision = fmap fromRational Postgres.field
```

and use that instead of `Postgres.field` for your fields corresponding to `numeric` values.

Comment: I should have gone deeper into the documentation. Thank you.